# Dump dictionary with a field containing an already encoded JSON string

Tags: python, json, avro

I'm JSON encoding a Dictionary using its avro schema to make it a stringify JSON:

```
import json
from datetime import datetime

import fastavro

message = {
    "name": "any",
    "ingestion_ts": datetime.utcnow(),
    "values": {
        "amount": 5,
        "countries": ["se", "nl"],
        "source": {
            "name": "web",
            "url": "whatever"
        }
    }
}
avro_schema = "" # import avro schema
fo = StringIO()
fastavro.json_writer(fo, avro_schema, [message])
message_str = fo.getvalue()
```

This works just as expected and returns me a JSON encoded string meeting the provided schema which looks like this:

```
'{"name": "any", "ingestion_ts": 1703192665965373, "values": {"amount": 5, "countries": ["se", "nl"], "source": {"name": "web", "url": "whatever"}}}'
```

However, now I need to wrap this str in a dictionary on the `payload` key, and publish it to a messaging queue which is expecting this schema:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "namespace": "CDCEvent",
  "name": "CDCEvent",
  "fields": [
    {
      "doc": "The system that generated the event",
      "type": "string",
      "name": "sys"
    },
    {
      "doc": "The operation performed on the event",
      "type": "string",
      "name": "op"
    },
    {
      "doc": "The content of the event",
      "type": "string",
      "name": "payload"
    }
  ]
}
```

So I'm just doing like this:

```
wrap = {
    "sys": "my_system",
    "op": "c",
    "payload": message_str
}
wrap_str = json.dumps(wrap)
```

The problem is that, as `message_str` has been previously encoded, when I encode the wrap again by calling `json.dumps`, the payload is being encoded again and the double quotes inside of it are being escaped, and the message cannot be properly decoded by the consumers:

```
'{"sys": "my_system", "op": "c", "payload": "{\\"name\\": \\"any\\", \\"ingestion_ts\\": 1703192665965373, \\"values\\": {\\"amount\\": 5, \\"countries\\": [\\"se\\", \\"nl\\"], \\"source\\": {\\"name\\": \\"web\\", \\"url\\": \\"whatever\\"}}}"}'
```

How could I avoid this double encoding? I've been trying to redesign the solution, but maybe I'm already obfuscated and I'm missing a pretty straightforward way. Remember that the queue is expecting a str for the `payload` field

Comment: is your message_str a Dictionary o a String?

Comment: @Wonka It's a String

Comment: then  try to change "payload": json.loads(message_str)

Comment: You either have to put up with double encoded json, or you don't encode in the first place and have everything single encoded.

Comment: @Wonka That would solve the double quotes, but then when I publish I receive an error because the payload field is not a string, but a map. I feel like there's a problem in how the payload filed is defined in the queue schema, as if you want to receive a stringfied JSON inside another stringfied JSON, then you would definitively get double quotes escaped. You have already answered the OG question so feel free to post your answer and I will mark it as correct, but: do you know how I can define the avro schema to accept any "dict-like" object, no matter its content, instead of a string?

Comment: Whatever uses `payload` needs to decode it if it doesn't want to display like that.

Answer (score 0):

When you say the message can't be decoded by consumers, how are they decoding it? If they take the `wrap_str` from your example and apply the following transformations, they will get the original message:

```py
wrapped_object = json.loads(wrap_str)

for record in fastavro.json_reader(StringIO(wrapped_object["payload"]), avro_schema):
    print(record)
```